# Grain effect doesn't work in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I read a tutorial and tried to create a grain effect on a rectangle. I created a rectangle, put a gradient on it and then via the **Effects Gallery** applied the grain effect, with an `Intensity: 74` and `Contrast: 50`, and `Grain mode: Sprinkles`.

This resulted in an appearance that DOES NOT resemble the one in the tutorial. The gradient is not grainy, but rather full of pixels, as you can see in the screenshot: 
[image]

I am desperate. How come the effect doesn't look grainy? Is there something wrong with the settings in my Illustrator? I am a webdesign newbie and would be very happy if anyone could help me out.

For your info, this is the tutorial I am referring to: http://vectips.com/tutorials/create-grainy-textures/

Comment: Can you share the AI file? Or the dimensions of the shape in pixels? I tried it myself an it worked fine. I think BrianC (see his comment) might be on track...

Comment: @cockypup how do I share a file?  well, the size of the rectangle is 250px x 180px.  I closed AI and reopened it, but still, it all looks pixelly

Comment: @cockypup did you create a NEW file?

Comment: @Ilan: yes, I created a new file. RGB, letter size, at 200% like KentMiller's one looks fine on my laptop.

Comment: @KentMiller: you could upload the file to a dropbox, for example, and share it. here is mine: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hab7iun7cqcndc1/Grain.ai

Comment: @cockypup Thank you for sharing the file. I had a look into it and created a rectangle next to yours. It's crazy, mine is still pixelly. Here is my file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iwekjypdfql8452/Grain%20comparison%20rectangles.ai

Comment: @KentMiller: Crazy is right! (1) If I open the file you sent me, the grain looks pixelated. (2) If I copy your rectangle from your file to a new file I create, then the grain looks fine. (3) If I create the grain on  my file, where it looks fine, and copy it to your file, then it looks pixelated. I noticed, though, you are using CS6. I am using CC. That is the only difference I can find between our files. Did your AI rasterized my rectangle when you opened my file? That usually means that something (font, style...) is not supported. Wild guess, CS6 handles the grain differently than  CC.

Answer (score 2):

look at the zoom levels, on your document its 100%, on the tutorial its 12.5%. i bet if you make the object you're trying to apply the filter to larger, you'll get the same result.

Comment: zoom matters in my case. If I zoom in too much I can see the grain as dots, like Kent Miller.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a tutorial and managed to solve like this:

Go to Effects > Document Raster Effects Settings and change the resolution to High (300ppi).

The grain effect should look fine now.

Answer (score -1):

The foreground and background colors need to be black and white.